# How to create custom registration form in magento for seller

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-core

How to make a custom registration and login form for sellers in magento.
I'm using marketpalace extension , and want to make a custom registration form.

Answer (score 0):

https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/How+to+Customize+Customer+Registration+Fields

If it doesn't work, please change the following template instead of two templates described in the article.

app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

And I think it's correct about controller and entity setup model.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I want to create a page named vendor registration with custom registration form not magento default registration form